# Facebook Debugger can't fetch open graph metadata

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a simple web page with includes a javascript redirect and has a few opengraph metadata.

The page parses correctly on OpenGraph.in ( http://bit.ly/pMehOj ) and even validates correctly on the w3c validator

But it miserably fails to parse with the Facebook Debugger ( http://bit.ly/nyGWlM )..

What could be wrong?

Comment: Try puting some content in the <body> tag. Maybe Facebook ignores empty pages so that its users won't get disappointed by clicking links that don't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You must have link to the open graph protocol

Add xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" in your html declaration as below :

`html lang="en" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"`

Comment: thank you for the tip, but xmlns:og is included already in the html declaration. adding the lang attribute doesn't help, it seems

Comment: oups sorry I've just figured out that I was checking the wrong URL i.e OpenGraph.in
Did you try to put <link rel="canonical" href="your_URL"/>